# Local max and absolute max

Tags: calculus

I have this doubt from many years.
What is the exact difference between local maxima and absolute maxima?
Similarly, difference between local minima and absolute minima?
also, Global max and minima.
If you can discuss with one function, which will cover all my doubts more well come.

Comment: Think of a local max as the top of a hill. It is higher than anything in the immediate **neighbourhood**. The global (absolute) max is Everest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a very common problem in calculus. I shall try to explain with the following group of functions.

Consider 1: 
$$x^3-2x^2 + 4$$
[Its graph is here.](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=x%5E3-2x%5E2%20%2b%204)

Notice that there is a local maxima near $x=0$. However, when you look at a larger domain, there are points that are greater than $(0, 4)$. Hence, this is a local maxima of the function. However, this is not a global maxima of the function, as it is not the highest point the function can go for the whole domain.

Consider 2:

$$x^2 - 4x + 7$$

Whose graph is [here.](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=x%5E2%20-%204x%20%2b%207)

Note that there is a global minimum at $x=2$ (I think). This is a global minima simply because there is no points below this point.

A global minima can be a local minima (for a small range) but a local minima might NOT be a global minima. This is just an introduction.